# How to you set the color of an ActionItem text

Tags: actionbarsherlock

Using themes, how do you set the color of the text of an ActionItem?  I can change the text color of the title, sub-title, and tabs but not the action items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `actionMenuTextColor` theme attribute!

It's defined as such:

```
<!-- Color for text that appears within action menu items. -->
<attr name="actionMenuTextColor" format="color|reference" />
```

Comment: Thanks I had assumed that attribute was for the overflow text.